# How do I add windows api to cmake such as synchapi.h?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmake

I'm porting a cross platform project to cmake. I've ported the linux half, but I don't know how to include windows api based libraries. In this particular case synchronization.lib which I believe contains synchapi.h. How do I instruct cmake to include it and is there a way to instruct cmake to look in a praticular place for all Windows based APIs?